# Recursive relationship getting id of the record

Tags: django

I have a table called "Activities" and for each activity I can have zero or many predecessors.

What I need is to have a ManyToManyField in this table, linked to itself, and store the id of the predecessor activity.

Does anyone can help on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
predecessor = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, null=True, blank=True)
```